# Phonegap application Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0. Worked a few weeks ago

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

i was creating some phonegap application two weeks ago and everything was compiling nice. Yesterday i just wanted to build android version with some changes and it crashes with:

```
C:\rpb\appSample>phonegap build -- --minSdkVersion=15
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build -- --minSdkVersion=15'...
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\rpb\appSample\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --minSdkVersion=15""

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\admin\.android

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_71

Running: C:\rpb\appSample\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\rpb\appSample\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -PcdvMinSdkVersion=15



FAILURE:
Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0.

     Searched in the following locations:

         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom

         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar

         file:/C:/Users/admin/.android/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom

         file:/C:/Users/admin/.android/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar

         file:/C:/Users/admin/.android/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom

         file:/C:/Users/admin/.android/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar

     Required by:

         :android:unspecified > com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1


> Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0.

     Searched in the following locations:

         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom

         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar

         file:/C:/Users/admin/.android/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom

         file:/C:/Users/admin/.android/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar

         file:/C:/Users/admin/.android/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom

         file:/C:/Users/admin/.android/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar

     Required by:

         :android:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.1


>
Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0.

     Searched in the following locations:

         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.pom

         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.jar

         file:/C:/Users/admin/.android/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.pom

         file:/C:/Users/admin/.android/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.jar

         file:/C:/Users/admin/.android/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.pom

         file:/C:/Users/admin/.android/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.0/cardview-v7-23.2.0.jar

     Required by:

         :android:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.1


>
Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0.

     Searched in the following locations:

         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom

         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar

         file:/C:/Users/admin/.android/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom

         file:/C:/Users/admin/.android/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar

         file:/C:/Users/admin/.android/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.pom

         file:/C:/Users/admin/.android/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.0/support-v4-23.2.0.jar

     Required by:

         :android:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0



* Try:

Run with
--stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
--info or
--debug option to get more log output.



BUILD FAILED




Total time: 2.881 secs


C:\rpb\appSample\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\rpb\appSample\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\rpb\appSample\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -P
cdvMinSdkVersion=15"

ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

My android sdk manager packages is updated and Android Support Library is in version 23.2.1

I had found that something crashed few weeks ago

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/i-cant-build-my-app-anymore-same-code-was-running-few-weeks-ago

and this guys say that i've to downgrade my packages. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

after full update of android sdk's 
and change in
../platform/android/project.properties
to
target=android-23

everything is working :)